# Draw a "squiggly line" in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to work out how to draw a squiggly line on an arbitrary SVG `path` element. The path is generated by a React Component. For example, I'm trying to replicate the line [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907082/draw-squiggly-line-along-a-curve-in-javascript):

[image: Squiggly Line Example]

Is there an easy way to do this in SVG and/or JavaScript generated paths?

I've considered joining up a series of curves using the `s` path command, but then I would need to calculate points along the curve. I've also considered some sort of displacement filter but I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems to me the easiest way would be step along the path. Then, at each step, insert a quadratic bezier curve with a control point that is half way between them and perpendicular to the curve. Then for the next step switch the side that the control point is on.

```js
function makeSquiggle(squigglePathId, followPathId, squiggleStep, squiggleAmplitude)
{
  var followPath = document.getElementById(followPathId);
  var pathLen = followPath.getTotalLength();

  // Adjust step so that there are a whole number of steps along the path
  var numSteps = Math.round(pathLen / squiggleStep);

  var pos = followPath.getPointAtLength(0);
  var newPath = "M" + [pos.x, pos.y].join(',');
  var side = -1;
  for (var i=1; i<=numSteps; i++)
  {
    var last = pos;
    var pos = followPath.getPointAtLength(i * pathLen / numSteps);

    // Find a point halfway between last and pos. Then find the point that is
    // perpendicular to that line segment, and is squiggleAmplitude away from
    // it on the side of the line designated by 'side' (-1 or +1).
    // This point will be the control point of the quadratic curve forming the
    // squiggle step.
    
    // The vector from the last point to this one
    var vector = {x: (pos.x - last.x),
                  y: (pos.y - last.y)};
    // The length of this vector
    var vectorLen = Math.sqrt(vector.x * vector.x + vector.y * vector.y);
    // The point halfwasy between last point and tis one
    var half = {x: (last.x + vector.x/2),
                y: (last.y + vector.y/2)};
    // The vector that is perpendicular to 'vector'
    var perpVector = {x: -(squiggleAmplitude * vector.y / vectorLen),
                      y: (squiggleAmplitude * vector.x / vectorLen)};
    // No calculate the control point position
    var controlPoint = {x: (half.x + perpVector.x * side),
                        y: (half.y + perpVector.y * side)};
    newPath += ("Q" + [controlPoint.x, controlPoint.y, pos.x, pos.y].join(','));
    // Switch the side (for next step)
    side = -side;
  }
  var squigglePath = document.getElementById(squigglePathId);
  squigglePath.setAttribute("d", newPath);
}


makeSquiggle("squiggle", "follow", 25, 20);
```

```css
#follow {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

#squiggle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="400">
  <path id="follow" d="M 50,300 C 100,100 300,0, 350,250 L 450,200"/>
  <path id="squiggle" d="M0,0"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. To get this to work in React without rendering an SVG node first I was able to use the `svg-path-properties` npm package.

Answer (score 3):

## Functional like solution

[image: Draw cos(x) around a curve]

**ATTENTION**:
f(x) is the curve that your squiggly line should follow and x0 is where you start to draw the squiggly line and xn is where you end this example assume that f(x) between x0 and xn is constantly growing

If you have a rasterised curve and the squiggly line that you want to draw is cos(x), you can find the points for draw the line as below:

- **squiggly line** the line that you want to draw
- **curve** the curve that **squiggly line** should follow
- **point0** is the point where **curve** start
- **pointN** is the point in **curve** for x == N
- **lenN** is the length of the curve from **point0** to **pointN**
- **h** (in the image) is the distance between **curve** and **squiggly line** in **pointN** and is *cos(**lenN**)*
- **alphaN** is the angle between the tangent of **curve** for x == n and the x-axis
- **a** (in the image) is *-cos(**alphaN**)*
- **b** (in the image) is *sin(**alphaN**)*
- **squigglyPointN** is **pointN**.x + a, **pointN**.y + b

```js
  'use strict'
  //
  // point = [int, int], point[0] = x, point[1] = y
  // rasterizedCurve = [point0, ...,pointN]
  //

  // int -> [int,...,int]
  function rangeFrom1ToN(N) {
    return Array(N).fill(0).map((x, index) => index).slice(1);
  }

  // [int, ...,int] -> [float, ..., float]
  function expandRange(Range, precision) {
    return Range.map(x => rangeFrom1ToN(precision).map((y, index) => x + 1/precision * index))
                .reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val));
  }

  function formatForSvg(points) {
    return points.map(x => x.toString()).reduce((acc, val) =>  {return acc + ' ' + val})
  }

  // rasterizedCurve, index -> int
  function derivative(curve, index){
    //
    // return dx' curve(x)
    //
    if (index === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    const point1 = curve[index - 1];
    const point2 = curve[index];
    return (point2[1] - point1[1]) / (point2[0] - point1[0]);
  }

  // rasterizedCurve -> rasterizedCurve
  function squiggleAroundCurve(x, y, curve, index) {
    const len = lenCurve(curve, index);
    const h = Math.sin(len);

    const b = Math.sin(Math.atan2(1, derivative(curve, index))) * h;
    const a = Math.cos(Math.atan2(1, derivative(curve, index))) * h;

    x -= a;
    y += b;
    return [x, y];
  }

  function pow2(x) {
    return Math.pow(x,2);
   }
    function dist(point1, point2) {
    return Math.sqrt(pow2(point2[0] - point1[0]) + pow2(point2[1] - point1[1]))
  }

  // rasterizedCurve, int -> int
  function lenCurve(rasterizedCurve, index) {
    const curve = rasterizedCurve.slice(0, index);
    return curve.reduce((sum, point, index) => {
      let len = 0;
      if (index > 0) {
        len = dist(point, curve[index - 1]);
      }
        return sum + len;
    }, 0);
  }


  const Curve = expandRange(rangeFrom1ToN(90),50).map(x => [x, (Math.log(x) * 15)]);
  const SquiggledCurve = Curve.map((point, index) => squiggleAroundCurve(point[0], point[1], Curve, index))
  function zoom(curve, w) {
    return curve.map(point => [point[0] * w, point[1] * w]);
  }
  function getNode(n, v) {
    n = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", n);
    for (var p in v)
      n.setAttributeNS(null, p.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(m, p, o, s) { return "-" + m.toLowerCase(); }), v[p]);
    return n
  }

  var svg = getNode("svg");

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.appendChild(svg);
    const r = getNode('polyline', { points:formatForSvg(zoom(SquiggledCurve, 10)), fill:'none', stroke:'black'});
    const c = getNode('polyline', { points:formatForSvg(zoom(Curve, 10)), fill:'none', stroke:'black'});
    svg.appendChild(r);
    svg.appendChild(c);
  }, 1000);
```

```css
  svg {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 900px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way would probably just join up Bézier curves and just offset and invert the values for every subsequent curve you wanted to create until you reached the desired length.

Comment: Yep, either sequential cubic Bezier or quadratic curves depending on the styling needs. :-)

Comment: I guess the challenge here is I would need to manually calculate the points along the path. It shouldn't be impossible, I just hoped there would be an easier way!

Answer (score 1):

I am glad I found this question, I was trying to draw a wavy line in SVG for a long time. Based on [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42443236/9861298) I created small reusable function for my needs:

```js
/**
 * Creates a "wavy" path following the given path with a specified amplitude
 * and stepLength values.
 */
export function createWavyPath(path: string, stepLength: number, amplitude: number) {
    const referencePath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    referencePath.setAttribute("d", path);

    const pathLength = referencePath.getTotalLength();
    const stepCount = Math.round(pathLength / stepLength);

    let pos = referencePath.getPointAtLength(0);
    const resultPath = [ `M ${pos.x},${pos.y}` ];
    let orientation = -1;

    for (let i = 1; i <= stepCount; i++) {
        const last = pos;
        pos = referencePath.getPointAtLength(i * pathLength / stepCount);

        // Find a point halfway between last and pos. Then find the point that is
        // perpendicular to that line segment, and is squiggleAmplitude away from
        // it on the side of the line designated by 'orientation' (-1 or +1).
        // This point will be the control point of the quadratic curve forming the
        // squiggle stepLength.
        
        // The vector from the last point to this one
        const vector = {
            x: pos.x - last.x,
            y: pos.y - last.y
        };

        const vectorLength = Math.sqrt(vector.x * vector.x + vector.y * vector.y);

        const mid = {
            x: last.x + vector.x / 2,
            y: last.y + vector.y / 2
        };

        const normalVector = {
            x: -amplitude * vector.y / vectorLength,
            y: amplitude * vector.x / vectorLength
        };

        const controlPoint = {
            x: mid.x + normalVector.x * orientation,
            y: mid.y + normalVector.y * orientation
        };

        resultPath.push(`Q ${controlPoint.x},${controlPoint.y},${pos.x},${pos.y}`);

        orientation *= -1;
    }

    return resultPath.join(" ");
}
```