# KonvaJS how to change the line style?

Tags: konvajs

I'm trying to create a drawing tablet with a mouse.

With KonvaJS, I can draw a line or an arrow.
How do I change the style of the line and the end of the arrow?

I use Konva. Arrow and Konva.Line and that's what I need.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Maybe something you can adapt for the line style here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128291/konva-js-waved-stroke-around-rect-element

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to implement such shapes.

(1) You can use [Konva.Path](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Path.html) and generate `data` attribute with SVG path manually (from your mouse movements).

(2) You can use [Konva.TextShape](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/TextPath.html) to draw arrow as a set of some symbols (like dots or dashes).

(3) You can use [Custom Shape](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Custom.html) to draw with native 2d canvas API.

Here is a demo with all of them:

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const getAngle = (points) => {
  const dx = points[1].x - points[0].x;
  const dy = points[1].y - points[0].y;
  const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  return Konva.Util.radToDeg(angle);
}

const createPathArrow = () => {
  return new Konva.Path({
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    stroke: 'red',
    fill: 'red',
    data: 'M 0 0 L 100 0 L 80 -10 L 90 0 L 80 10 L 100 0'
  })
};



const createTextPathArrow = (points) => {
  const [p1, p2] = points;
  const group = new Konva.Group({
    x: 50,
    y: 150
  });
  group.add(new Konva.TextPath({
    stroke: 'red',
    text: '| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | ',
    data: `M ${p1.x} ${p1.y} L ${p2.x} ${p2.y}`
  }));
  group.add(new Konva.Text({
    x: p2.x,
    y: p2.y,
    text: '➤',
    fill: 'red',
    fontSize: 25,
    offsetY: 25 / 2,
    offsetX: 25 / 2,
    rotation: getAngle(points)
  }))
  return group;
};

const createSceneArrow = () => {
  return new Konva.Shape({
    x: 50,
    y: 250,
    stroke: 'red',
    length: 100,
    arcSize: 10,
    sceneFunc: (ctx, shape) => {
      const arcSize = shape.getAttr('arcSize');
      const number = shape.getAttr('length') / arcSize;
      ctx.beginPath();
      for(var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
          ctx.moveTo(i * arcSize, 0);
          const midX = (i * arcSize + arcSize / 2);
          const midY = 0;
          if (i % 2 === 0) {
            ctx.arc(midX, midY, arcSize / 2, Math.PI, 0, 1);            
          } else {
            ctx.arc(midX, midY, arcSize / 2, Math.PI, 0);            
          }
      }
      ctx.fillStrokeShape(shape);
    }
  })
}

const points = [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 100, y: 30}];

layer.add(createPathArrow());
layer.add(createTextPathArrow(points));
layer.add(createSceneArrow())
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^8/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I'am use Konva.TextPath for line and Konva.Image for arrow. Thanks